# 1068 multiple primary key defined in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1068

I export (with update) my existing MySQL backup and import it to another PC via PHPAdmin but it gives below error message. I need to just replace existing database on backup PC. Is it possible to do this?

> #1068 - Multiple primary key defined

Comment: Did these answers help you? If not, let us know so we can continue to help. Otherwise, would you mind marking the most helpful answer as "accepted"? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, add `drop table` option in your export, then on import, your table will be dropped and recreated. This will avoid pk conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

To do a wholesale replacement of an existing database...

One option is to drop the existing database and re-create it. But make sure you really want to do this, and that you are doing it on the MySQL instance you really want to do it on:

```
DROP DATABASE mydb ;
CREATE DATABASE mydb ;
```

Note that this may have an effect on granted privileges, you may need to re-grant privileges on the new database.  (In the CREATE DATABASE statement, include a specification for the default characterset and collation, if those differ from the setting of the instance variables.)

SQLyog has a convenient "empty database" menu option, which drops all of the objects in the database without having to drop the database and re-create it. (This may have an effect on privileges granted to individual database objects.)

I'm not sure if phpmyadmin has an equivalent function. To roll your own, it's a matter of querying the `information_schema` tables to identify all tables, views, procedures, etc.

For example, to generate a list of the `DROP TABLE` statements, you could run a query something like this:

```
 SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE `',t.table_schema,'`.`',t.table_name,'` ;') AS stmt
   FROM information_schema.tables t
  WHERE t.table_schema = 'foo' ;
```

If the tables have foreign keys, you can either set the `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` for the session, or execute the drop statements in the appropriate order, etc. And repeat for the other object types: `information_schema.routines`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

instead of drop database, empty it instead:

```
truncate tablename
```

(then add the pk again)
When you do it this way don't have to recreate all tables and columns again.

Comment: Do you mean truncate database? If so, the code is wrong. If not, how does truncating tables help with PK conflicts?
Please clarify!